# Why does Webots 2022b not support VRLM97?

Tags: webots

I am creating a complex robot and I do not know what is better:

1. Use Webots 2023a and use CADshape. The .DAE doesn't look great because it's a mesh.
2. Use Webots 2021b and import VRLM97. It looks much better.

Does this decision impact the performance of the simulation? I will use 8 robots at the same time.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The VRML97 import feature was removed from Webots R2023a because it is replaced by the [Mesh](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/mesh) and [CadShape](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/cadshape) nodes.

Referring to an external CAD file is way better than including it inside the world or proto file for several reasons:

1. It is easier to maintain the shapes: you can edit/regenerate the CAD file independently of your simulation worlds or proto files.
2. It makes the world and proto files lighter, more readable and easier to maintain.

If your DAE file doesn't look great because it is a mesh, I would recommend you to use the `Mesh` node instead of the `CadShape` node to import it. This way, you will be able to set a nice appearance for it in Webots. See for example [metal](https://webots.cloud/proto?search=metal) or [plastic](https://webots.cloud/proto?search=plastic) appearances available in Webots.

You may also want to use the `indexMaterial` field of the `Mesh` node to be able to specify different materials for every part of your CAD model.

Webots version R2023a is the best choice in terms of performance and features compared to R2021b. So, I would definitely recommend using the newest version.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*